# Is it possible in Castle Windsor to make a service with dependency on property of another component?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Let's say I have `ISettings` with a property `string Setting1` and I have

```
public class MyComponent : IMyService
{
    public MyComponent(string setting1)
    {
        // set fields
    }
}
```

Is it possible to wire up Windsor to say that ISettings.Setting1 should be used to satisfy the dependency of MyComponent?

Comment: Yes it is possible. See http://kozmic.net/2010/02/15/new-castle-windsor-feature-ndash-typed-arguments/ but why not have `MyComponent` just take `ISettings` as a constructor parameter?

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt - do you want credit for providing this link? If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest 2 options.

First, use ISettings as dependency and use Setting1 where necessary

```
public class MyComponent : IMyService
{
    public MyComponent(ISettings settings)
    {
        // access settings.Setting1
    }
}
```

Second, Windsor .DependsOn function to pass some primitive properties to component.

```
container.Register(
                Component.For<IMyService >()
                .ImplementedBy<MyComponent >()
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("setting1", ISettingsInstance.Setting1));
```